# Excel, Formula for conditional Access to certain cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get my worksheet to allow input in a cell where there is a protected formula, on condition that information on another cell doesn't exist.

I have two columns B (Employee Number) and C (Name). I have a separate data sheet with a list of employee numbers and names in the cells next to them(Columns B & C).

On sheet1 in Column C I have the formula

> =IF(OR(C5="",NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C5,Data!B:B,0)))),"",VLOOKUP(C5,Data!B:C,2,FALSE))

Now, I can hide and protect the cells with the formula, but then if an employee number that is not on the data sheet is entered, I cannot enter a name into column C.

If I just hide the formula, but do not protect the cells, I can enter a name into the cell on Column C, but if the name was misspelled and I delete the name to start again, it also deletes the formula too!

Is there any way to get the cells in column C keep the formulas, and allow manual entry if the employee number in column B doesn't exist?

[image: Excel Data Sheet]

Comment: Erm probably not. Perhaps the column can be locked and named "Search result" or something and another column next to it with simple `=D3` referencing that isn't locked

Comment: Or Manual override column next to it and have the first if statement refer to that manual override column?

Comment: That will only move the problem, not cure it. In the unlocked column, having the formula `=D3` will have the same result as in column D. Someone enters an employee number in C and the new column will show the name. As soon as someone deletes the name accidentally, it will also delete even that formula! Would a way round be possibly using VBA? I don't know enough about VBA to know if it could be done, let alone know how!

Comment: Yeah you could hook up a button to a simple VBA script doing the same thing. Would be a good simple introduction to Macros. |Some people advise using macro recorder and looking at what it does but there are so many bad practices picked up that way. You will want to look at using a for each loop over your range assessing the other range using a counter or offset. Drop in what you have tried and I can advise accordingly or help out.

Comment: How about using `Data Validation`?  Just mark your employee number column as the list that people can either pick from or type in.  Otherwise, it will give them error messages.